# Hash function in Python is not giving the answer I want

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I am practising Python questions on HackerRank. [Here's the question](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/python-tuples/problem).

This is my solution:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    i = tuple(map(int,input().split()))
    print(hash(i))
```

Desired Output is

```
3713081631934410656
```

However, the output I get is

```
-3550055125485641917
```

Why is that the case?

Someone tested my code, and it gave them the desired code. I tried copying and pasting my code again. Still didn't work.

[image]

### Edit

It started working. I had to select Pypy3 (shoutout Bereal). Also, big ups to Chepner for pointing out Python3 Hash functionality.

Comment: I copy-pasted your code there, and got exactly what's expected.

Comment: Tangentially, the code you put inside `if _    name__ == ’__main__’:` should be absolutely trivial. The condition is only useful when you `import` this code; if all the useful functionality is excluded when you `import`, you will never want to do that anyway. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/69778466/874188

Comment: I removed the `if __name__ == '__main__'`  part, still the same problem.

Comment: is it being called a failure,  they list the output as "Sample" output.   The hash value could vary depending on a number of factors.

Comment: FWIW, `hash((1,2))` produces the negative value in Python 3.9, the positive in Python 2.7, on my local machine.

Comment: Choose "Pypy 3" in the dropdown menu above the code.

Comment: @LhasaDad yeah, it shows test case failed. The problem wants the value to be exactly as the desired output. I don't know why am I getting that value.

Comment: I got OP's result.

Comment: i think @chepner has the real reason the value is different.

Comment: Shoutout to bereal and chepner for pointing that out. Thanks <3

Comment: Not thrilled with a test written that is so dependent on the environment settings.

Comment: in the real world you would calculate the hash of two tuples and check if the hash matched (two tuples that were the same)  here you have a predefined value that could vary as we saw with the answer

Answer (score 1):

From the discussion section: "THE TEST is for PYPY3, not Python3. Make sure to change language to Pypy3 !!!"

source: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/python-tuples/forum

In general @Inshaullah, it's best to check out the discussion forums on these sites if there's problems along these lines.